# Get XML namespace prefix in Go using Unmarshal

Tags: xml, go

I would like to know if it is possible to get the XML namespace prefix using the 
`Unmarshal` method in `encoding/xml`.

For example, I have:

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</application>
```

I would like to know how to retrieve the `xs` defining the prefix for XMLSchema, without having to use the `Token` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get it like every other attribute:

```
type App struct {
    XS string `xml:"xs,attr"`
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/2IOmkX1Jov.

It gets trickier if you also have an actual `xs` attribute, sans `xmlns`. Even if you add the namespace URI to `XS`'s tag, you will probably [get an error](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11724).

**EDIT:** If you want to get *all* declared namespaces, you can define a custom `UnmarshalXML` on your element and scan it's attributes:

```
type App struct {
    Namespaces map[string]string
    Foo        int `xml:"foo"`
}

func (a *App) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    a.Namespaces = map[string]string{}
    for _, attr := range start.Attr {
        if attr.Name.Space == "xmlns" {
            a.Namespaces[attr.Name.Local] = attr.Value
        }
    }

    // Go on with unmarshalling.
    type app App
    aa := (*app)(a)
    return d.DecodeElement(aa, &start)
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/u4RJBG3_jW.

Comment: I can not deduce in advance what will be the prefix value.When you "mix" xml specifications, you use prefix to distinguish the spec you are using. I know that XMLSchema is defined with a specified URI. In the algorithm, I first search  if a namespace has been declared and I would like to have to retrieve the namespace prefix value.

Comment: @yageek So you want to get information about all declared namespaces? If so, see edit.

Comment: So it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Currently (Go 1.5), it does not seems to be possible.

The only solution I found, was to use rewind the element:

```
func NewDocument(r io.ReadSeeker) (*Document, error) {

    decoder := xml.NewDecoder(r)

    // Retrieve xml namespace first
    rootToken, err := decoder.Token()


    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var xmlSchemaNamespace string

    switch element := rootToken.(type) {
    case xml.StartElement:

        for _, attr := range element.Attr {
            if attr.Value == xsd.XMLSchemaURI {
                xmlSchemaNamespace = attr.Name.Local
                break
            }
        }
    }

    /* Process name space */

    // Rewind
    r.Seek(0, 0)

    // Standart unmarshall
    decoder = xml.NewDecoder(r)
    err = decoder.Decode(&w)

    /* ... */
}
```