# How to get xml prefix in golang in dynamic xml without struct

Tags: xml, go, soap, encoding

Suppose I have an XML like this

```xml
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <contents>
            <article>
                <category>Server</category>
                <title>Connect to Oracle Server using Golang and Go-OCI8 on Ubuntu</title>
                <url>/go-oci8-oracle-linux/</url>
            </article>
            <!-- ... -->
        </contents>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I also have common struct like this

```golang
type envelope struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Attrs   []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
    Body    struct {
        InnerXML []byte `xml:",innerxml"`
    }
}
```

The problem is how to get the word `soap` (from `soap:Envelope`)in the most outer wrapper

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get XML namespace prefix in Go using Unmarshal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35044019/get-xml-namespace-prefix-in-go-using-unmarshal)

Comment: @Inian seems like no because the prefix that I want to know is the most outer prefix which is `soap`. The XML Namespace can be more than one, from my XML the namespaces are `ns` and `soap`

Comment: @DavidAsync the only thing that I know of that can help you is [`RawToken`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.19.1#Decoder.RawToken) which specifically says *"does not translate name space prefixes"*. Note that `RawToken` cannot be used within a custom `xml.Unmarshaler` implementation. Example: https://go.dev/play/p/qNlnAWSYASG

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the limitations of this solution; please kindly point them out in the comments.

1. You can use your struct as is to capture the root node's prefix URI
2. get the slice of attributes, each of which has a struct that maps a URI to a name for the prefix
3. iterate the attributes and try to match each attribute's value to the node's prefix URI, then
4. save the attribute's local name, the name of the prefix

(I think that all makes sense, I called the right things by the right names)

Here's what it looks like:

```golang
var e envelope
xml.Unmarshal(data, &e)

var rootURI, rootPrefix string

rootURI = e.XMLName.Space
for _, attr := range e.Attrs {
    if attr.Name.Space == "xmlns" && attr.Value == rootURI {
        rootPrefix = attr.Name.Local
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(rootPrefix, rootURI)
```

When I run that with your sample XML, it prints:

```
soap http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/
```

Here's the complete demo, https://go.dev/play/p/x3FKfkCW64x.

Answer (score 0):

I found a golang library that is called https://github.com/beevik/etree so my code will be like this

```golang
func getPrefix(xmlbytes []byte) string {
    doc := etree.NewDocument()

    if err := doc.ReadFromBytes(xmlbytes); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    return doc.Root().Space
}
```